# Why does RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash have a “hash algorithm identifier” parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, signing, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Since [RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) verifies an already hashed message - why does it need to know which hash algorithm was used?

When asking about the `SignHash` method  , [it was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384715/why-does-rsacryptoserviceprovider-signhash-have-a-hash-algorithm-identifier-pa) that the reason there is [for communicating the hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843336/why-does-signhash-need-to-know-what-hash-algorithm-was-used) (and not for actual use in the signing). But that won't explain it in this case. (since it's not an `out` parameter.)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142k6c98%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) : "Verifies that a digital signature is valid by determining the hash value in the signature using the provided public key and comparing it to the provided **hash** value." - the parameter is _already_ a hash.

Answer (score 3):

That's because PKCS#1 encoding of signature includes hash function OID in RSA-encrypted data block.

Comment: Thanks. So if I enter the wrong algorithm - it'll tell me it failed simply because the algorithms don't match. If so - it seems that the reason for the algorithm parameter in `SignHash` is also for the same reason, and _not_ for communicating the hash as was suggested in the answers I linked to. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: As far as I remember the reason for including hash OID in signature is for protection as well - if we have weaker hash algorithm with the same hash length, we can (theoretically) modify signed data and produce the same signature, using other hashing algorithm.

Comment: +1 yep, that's just it. See also ISO 9796 where the hash ID needs to be communicated out of band even though it may be present in the signature. Otherwise an attacker may force you to accept a signature using a broken hash function. Normally not a huge risk, but better safe than sorry.