# Digital Signatures: Encrypting the Hash vs Signing the Hash?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, certificate

I'm trying to implement SHA256-RSA digital signatures and I'm confused with the terminology and implementation in C#.

AFAIK, "signing a file" is to generate the hash of a file, and then encrypt that hash. I've also heard the phrase "signing the hash". Is this the same thing? Or is this hashing a hash and then encrypting hash'?

Here's the code in question:

```
public void SignatureTest(byte[] data, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    var sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

    var hashOfData = sha256.ComputeHash(data);

    var encryptedHash = rsa.Encrypt(hashOfData, false);
    var encryptedHashOAEP = rsa.Encrypt(hashOfData, true);            
    var signedHash = rsa.SignHash(hashOfData, "SHA256");

    //Shouldn't one of these be true?
    var false1 = CompareAsBase64Str(encryptedHash, signedHash);
    var false2 = CompareAsBase64Str(encryptedHashOAEP, signedHash);

    //This is the one that actually matches
    var true1 = CompareAsBase64Str(signedHash, rsa.SignData(data, sha256));
}

public bool CompareAsBase64Str(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    return (Convert.ToBase64String(b1) == Convert.ToBase64String(b2));
}
```

Here's what MSDN says on RSACryptoServiceProvider:

SignHash() Computes the signature for the specified hash value **by encrypting it** with the private key.

Encrypt() **Encrypts data** with the RSA algorithm.

Shouldnt SignHash(hash) and Encrypt(hash) be the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The answer given by zaitsman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41072090/5030434) is a good explanation of the topics related to your questions and I think should be the accepted answer, but just to help tie it back to your specific question of why encrypting the hash doesn't give you the same result as signing the hash (the `rsa.SignHash(hashOfData, "SHA256")` in your code):

Signing a hash doesn't *just* encrypt the hash data -- it also encrypts the name (or some identifier) of the hashing algorithm used to generate the hash along with it. Without that, the receiver wouldn't know what algorithm to use when computing their own hash (of the message being sent) to compare with the one they just decrypted in order to verify the authenticity of the message (which, of course, is the whole point).

When you encrypted the hash yourself (with `rsa.Encrypt(hashOfData, false)` and `rsa.Encrypt(hashOfData, true)`), you only encrypted the hash data and not *the combination* of hash data *and* algorithm identifier (`"SHA256"` in your code). In other words, you encrypted *different data*, so you got *different (encrypted) results*.

The reason the return value of that `SignHash` call *does match* the value returned by `rsa.SignData(data, sha256)` is that the latter method does the same thing, except it does the hashing and hash signing as one operation, so you don't have to compute the hash as a separate step if you don't need it for any purpose other than signing it.

From [RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.hashdata(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN:

> Computes the hash value of the specified data and signs it.

Also see: [Why does SignHash need to know what hash algorithm was used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843336/why-does-signhash-need-to-know-what-hash-algorithm-was-used)

Comment: Thanks! In addition to your information about the identifier, I found [Pavel Ognev's response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12140124/6258530) on the thread you linked. Hopefully I can create the correct padding for my data so that the encrypted data' (via `rsa.Encrypt()`) matches the signature (via `rsa.SignData()`)

Answer (score 11):

You need to separate concerns, this will help you understand the terminology.

Any arbitrary blob of data can be `hash`ed and/or `encrypt`ed in any combination.
`Hash` means: use a cryptographic algorithm to generate a value that is irreversible (that is, simply by knowing algorithm and hash you are unable to reconstitute original data) and consistent (that is, given the same data and algorithm, the value of the hash produced is always the same).

`Encrypt` means: use a cryptographic algorithm to encipher data (altogether or in blocks) with a given key (a key can be symmetric or asymmetric).

`Sign` means: `Hash` the data and `Encrypt` the hash with a given key. Then, given the pair (for asymmetric) or same (for symmetric) key, a consumer can validate that:

1. hash is matching, that means the data has not been altered in transit
2. hash did come from the source that at least has the pair key (for asymmetric) or same key (for symmetric)

Comment: Thanks! I was more so confused on the term "signing the hash" as referred to [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6335/is-signing-a-hash-instead-of-the-full-data-considered-secure), [here](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/hsm-digital-signature-faq/), and other places.

Correct me if I'm mistaken: so the verb "sign" is a different process in "signing the file" vs "signing the hash". To sign a file is to generate a hash of that file, then encrypt that hash with additional data identifying the hash. To sign a hash is to just encrypt the hash with the additional identifying data?

Comment: @nr-91 `Sign` is exactly the same process no matter what you're signing. when you're transferring really large chunks of data (think: 10s of GBs) the process of signing the whole file may be time consuming as typically the data in the signature is enveloped somehow. However, you may be able to calculate the hash while streaming blocks of data to the client and then sign just that to validate authenticity. This way, the data comes unsigned and unencrypted, but the client can generate the hash themselves (while receiving) and then validate that against the 'signed hash' message.

Comment: So `Sign(hash)` is the same process as `Sign(data)`?
`Sign(object obj)
{
    var hash = CalculateHash(obj);
    var hashAndPadding = hash + CreatePadding();
    return Sign(hashAndPadding);
}
`
This is infinite recursion.

Comment: @nr-91 Em no. pseudo-code: `Sign(object obj, Key key) { var hash = CalculateHash(obj); var envelope = new Envelope(object, hash, key); return envelope; }`